# Transação PHP PDO com vários objetos

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

A ideia seria essa: Tenho 3 classes, uma para conexão ao banco, outra para Usuários e outra para Produto.

A classe Usuário com o banco de dados `tb_usuarios`.

A classe Produto com o banco de dados `tb_produtos`.

Faço o `INSERT` em cada classe Usuário e Produto.

Estou tentando agora em dois objetos fazer uma transação com o código abaixo.

```
try {
    require_once 'Connection.php';

    $conn = new Connection();
    $conn->connectionDB()->beginTransaction();

    $objuser = new Usuario();
    $objuser->insertUser("Nome Teste", "teste@mail.com");

    $objproduct = new Produto();
    $objproduct->insertProduct("Nome Produto", "Preço", "Data");

    $conn->connectionDB()->commit();
} 

catch(PDOException $ex) {
    $conn->connectionDB()->rollBack();
    echo $ex.getMessage();
}
```

A falha ocorre no trecho abaixo:

```
$conn->connectionDB()->rollBack();
```

Comment: Se ele entrou na `catch`. A falha ocorre no `try`. O que o `$ex.getMessage();` informa?

Comment: Outra coisa esse `$conn->connectionDB()->rollBack();` não pode ser usado pois o objeto `$conn` não foi instanciado dentro do `catch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

você precisa incluir a instância da conexão antes do try, para que esteja disponível no catch.

```
require_once 'Connection.php';

$conn = new Connection();

try {

    $conn->connectionDB()->beginTransaction();

    $objuser = new Usuario();
    $objuser->insertUser("Nome Teste", "teste@mail.com");

    $objproduct = new Produto();
    $objproduct->insertProduct("Nome Produto", "Preço", "Data");

    $conn->connectionDB()->commit();
} 

catch(PDOException $ex) {
    $conn->connectionDB()->rollBack();
    echo $ex.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Fiz uma classe de transação e passei os INSERT que precisava. Fiz a conexão antes do try e funcionou.